# Cannot align bootstrap submit button in form?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used bootstrap form but submit button is not getting aligned below Name and Number field in form. I tried to use various css styles but could not align it. See screenshot submit button is not aligned properly.

In app.js:

```
    function editContact(id) {
    document.getElementById("search").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("contactlist").style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById("editcontact").style.display = '';
    document.getElementById("editcontact").innerHTML = 
        `
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputName">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" aria-describedby="namehelp" placeholder="Enter Name ">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputNumber">Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNumber" placeholder="Enter Number">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputGroup">Group</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputGroup" placeholder="Enter Group">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
        `;
}
```

In index.css:

```
.form-group{
    padding-left: 30px;
    padding-right: 30px;
}

.form .btn-primary{
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

I also tried to wrap submit button inside `div` tag but still no effect.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
form .btn-primary{
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

not .form this should also be margin otherwise the text would be shifted 30 pixels but the button remain in the same place

Comment: Just incase anyone would want to see CSS's Box Model Spec, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding padding to `.form-group` and `.btn` what you can do is add padding to the form itself, just add a class to the form and add css against it.

Working example -

```js
function editContact(id) {
    document.getElementById("editcontact").innerHTML = 
        `
        <form class="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputName">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" aria-describedby="namehelp" placeholder="Enter Name ">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputNumber">Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNumber" placeholder="Enter Number">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputGroup">Group</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputGroup" placeholder="Enter Group">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
        `;
}

editContact(1);
```

```css
.form{
  padding: 0 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap@3.3.7" data-semver="3.3.7" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div id="editcontact">
      
    </div>  
  </body>

</html>
```

Notice, I added `.form` class, and adding to it.
Here is a plunker of the above snippet https://plnkr.co/edit/R2ku3opNtn3KsBDYKYr3?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

wrap button inside form-group div (new ) P.S try this snippet in expanded snippet view

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputName">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" aria-describedby="namehelp" placeholder="Enter Name ">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputNumber">Number</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNumber" placeholder="Enter Number">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="InputGroup">Group</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputGroup" placeholder="Enter Group">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: In some cases it would make sense to put the form controls in a `<span></span>` or a bootstrap `.col-*-*`. The `.form-group` class would work but is misused in this case as far as semantics go. We would expect some sort of input element and a label element inside the `.form-group` not a button.

Comment: thank you @MarkCarpenterJr i will keep it in mind .(that it is a bad practice)